# How to dynamically load internal xaml in Silverlight 3 at runtime?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-3.0, canvas

I have a few **internal** *Canvas* xaml files which I want to load dynamically at runtime.  For example, I want to display the *Canvas* in a page.  However, I cannot seem to get it to work. I've tried using *XamlReader*, *Application.LoadComponent*, and using an *XDocument*; all to no avail.  I cannot seem to find the best practice for this on-line either.

The *Canvases* are stored like this:  MyApp/Resources/Logos/Logo1.xaml.  I'm not sure if Logo1.xaml should have a build action of "Component" or "Resource".  In any case, using the URI of "MyApp;components/Resources/Logos/Logo1.xaml" seems to be correct, but *Application.LoadComponent* gets an XamlParseException at Line 0 Position 0.

Here's a pseudo-example of Logo1.xaml:

```
<Canvas
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="286.233" Height="143.425">

    <Canvas>

        <Path />

        <Path />

        <Path />

        <Path />

    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

The data for the path elements has been omitted for brevity's sake.

Any ideas?

Comment: The normal route is to use `XamlReader`. What error do you get?

Comment: There's a whole chapter on this in my Silverlight book which is unfortunately at home right now. This evening (in about four hours) I can give you as much info as you like.

Comment: I don't know the answer but this sample is doing it so perhaps that will help http://silverlight.net/samples/sl2/dlrconsole/index.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work using build action "Resource" and the XamlLoader with a ContentControl:

```
var resourceName = string.Format("MyApp;component/Resources/Logos/{0}.xaml", logoName);
var uri = new Uri(resourceName, UriKind.Relative);
var streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

string xaml = null;

using (var resourceStream = streamResourceInfo.Stream)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(resourceStream))
    {
        xaml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

Canvas canvas = XamlReader.Load(xaml) as Canvas;

this.contentControl.Content = canvas;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377146/how-to-dynamically-load-internal-xaml-in-silverlight-3-at-runtime/1380178#1380178) is not intuitive to me, but may suit some people.

I generally feel more comfortable with `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` and `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`. I borrowed a code piece from MSDN. For a test, just create a new Canvas at runtime:

```
Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas()
```

Then, just write it out, with `File.WriteAllText`, simple too, avoiding all the URI stuff, which as a beginner I find confusing. Lastly, just read it back in as above. Done. This proves you can simply just read in some valid code for a canvas from a text file, and it can be loaded dynamically.

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas();
    newCanvas.Name = "newCanvas";
    string savedCanvas = XamlWriter.Save(newCanvas);
    File.WriteAllText("savedCanvas.txt", savedCanvas);
    savedCanvas = File.ReadAllText("savedCanvas.txt");
    // Load the canvas
    StringReader stringReader2 = new StringReader(savedCanvas);
    XmlReader xmlReader2 = XmlReader.Create(stringReader2);
    Canvas newCreatedCanvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader2);
    this.Content = newCreatedCanvas;
}
```

The ideas are [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590398.aspx) as below:

> XamlReader.Load Method (XmlReader)
>
> .NET Framework 4
>
> Reads the XAML input in the specified [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) and returns an object that is the root of the corresponding object tree.
>
> **Namespace:**  [System.Windows.Markup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.aspx)
>
> **Assembly:**  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)